# How to get length of a txt file with javascript

Tags: javascript, activex

I'm using the ActiveX functions with files such as writing about them for example. I need to know if it was possible to get the length in lines of the file read. 
I use to control when it is finished flow.AtEndOfStream, but now I need to get the length of lines in a file, you can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML File upload form:

```
<input type="file" id="fileinput" name="fileinput">
```

Event listener for file upload form:

```
document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', showLength);
```

Callback for listener:

```
function showLength(fileUploadEvent) {
    var linesArray;

    var reader = new FileReader();

    // set up the event handler for when the file is loaded
    reader.onload = function() {
        console.log("Total file length: " + this.result.length);

        linesArray = this.result.split('\n');

        for (var i=0, l=linesArray.length; i<l; i++) {
            console.log("Line #" + i + " Length: " + linesArray[i].length);
        }
    }
    // fire off the loading of the file as a text file
    reader.readAsText(fileUploadEvent.target.files[0]);
}
```

Full plunkr example here http://plnkr.co/edit/Kcf4LAlxN5Hqgjg0cEJb

Comment: The lines are in the linesArray. It is writing the length to the console, but the content is in linesArray and you can do whatever you want with it. Total length is this.result.length. Total number of lines is linesArray.length. What more are you looking for?